# Using knife project method to make a shape into the mesh

Tags: modeling, knife-tool

I’m practising some modelling methods, although I know knife project method is not the best because it can make a mess of the topology, I couldn’t figure out another approach to achieve this particular shape modelled in the middle of the main mesh. I’d like some feedback what other way could I had approached to get that shape made within the main mesh.

[image]

Comment: Try to start with more simplified geometry  connected without n-gons. Use subsurface modifier to round curved parts and Edge Crease Shift+E 1 to keep corners sharp. Similar to this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/185599/2214

Comment: I am giving it an attempt with the subdivision which is very clean topology, but takes more consideration and planning how to layout the vertices. https://ibb.co/rHnxnTQ

Comment: Still complicated :-) Planning? Sure, blender is not AI, but Limited Disolve with keeping quads operator could be helpful if exists :-) if none here I will try to answer in hour or two.

Comment: I managed to make some progress with the subdivision modifier. But i'd like ot see the limited dissolve and quads which you stated. The more techniques I see the more skills Ill learn, if you'd like to share a screen shot or quick video demo. This is what I got so far, but I wont rest here, I'm always looking for improvement. https://ibb.co/7Rw5KqJ

Comment: Really curious why you are getting downvoted. Either way, Moonboots SUBD approach is probably the cleanest way to attack this problem. But you can probably also get away with boolean/bevel and cleanup as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do the other way around, beginning with the shape then extrude to get your rectangular object, at the end when you'll give it the *Subdivision Surface* modifier it will just need a bit of work to get the sharp angles:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks heaps guys, both ways we 1000 times better approach method then the mess I made. Moonboots methods was a bit more simpler for me to model, and didn't even think about starting from inside shape and then working my way out. the result: https://ibb.co/mFZdxM4

Answer (score 7):

Try to start with more simplified geometry connected without n-gons.

- Start with 10 sided *Circle* and continue extrude, scale, as needed)
- Use *Subdivision Surface* modifier to round curved parts
- and **Edge Crease** <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> 1 to keep corners sharp.

Similar to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/185599/2214).

[image]

[image]

Note: I probably used too low topology, when I would like to bevel edges now, I would have to add another loops (alternatively use bevelling on shader level).